# Because of forgetfulness, I caused other Jews to eat dairy after meat. What can I do to atone?

Tags: meat-and-milk, repentance-teshuvah, lifnei-iver

I baked carob brownies for tu b'shvat *with butter.* The next day, I made pareve barley soup and a dairy dessert. I took these (& other pareve stuff) to my son's house for a tu b'shvat seder. They asked if the soup was pareve, because they had eaten meat. I forgot about the brownies, & I said that everything was pareve except the dessert.  The next day, I realized that the brownies, which everyone ate, were dairy.  So, I had put a michshol lifnei iver due to forgetfulness.  I feel terrible.  What should I do to atone?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accidentally served a guest meat and milk](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/56387/accidentally-served-a-guest-meat-and-milk)

Comment: @DannySchoemann Except this may be [less of an issue](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/11816): `In Yoreh Deah 89:1, Rabbi Yosef Karo... states... that one must` [by rabbinic law] `wait six hours after consuming meat before eating dairy. On the opposite end of the spectrum is Rema.. who posits that the rule is to not consume meat and dairy in the same meal. While Rema maintains that, according to the letter of the law, one may eat a meat meal, recite Birkat Hamazon and then immediately begin a dairy meal, he asserts that Ashkenazic Jewry has accepted the custom of waiting between meals...`

Answer (score 1):

There's good news, and there's better news. The good news is this has happened to many others before you, and the better news is not to worry about it. (Well, try to educate yourself and be more careful, but it needs no atonement.)

As Fred noted in his comments, as long as the dairy was a different meal than the meat, you've satisfied the bare-minimum rabbinic requirement, so we're just talking at the level of custom (according to many).

But I'll tell you a better story! Years ago at Ner Israel yeshiva near Baltimore, there was a complicated mix-up and they served real, dairy ice cream instead of pareve ices for dessert right after the shabbos meat meal. The kitchen coordinator felt terrible, but the mashgiach told him not to worry about it. The Nesivos HaMishpat writes that a mistaken violation of a rabbinic prohibition needs no atonment. (And as long as the ice cream and cholent weren't *cooked* together, it would be rabbinically prohibited; and as above, if a different course, it might not even be that.)