# Informing people of a sin that you made them do

Tags: halacha-theory, sin

Is there any obligation to inform someone of a sin that came about because of you, which they will never realise unless you reveal it, and it is already too late (and won't be repeated by not informing)?

For example, if one had guests and accidentally served a milky dessert after a meaty meal, *Chas veshalom*.

---

**Points that would be good to address:**

- Perhaps the answer differs if it was, from their point of view,
  *b'ones* (they were compelled e.g. the dessert wasn't detectably milky) or *b'shogeg* (they share some blame due
  to their negligence e.g. if one served the dessert in the packaging and anyone
  had an opportunity to look at the label, but they didn't)?
- What about if it was *d'oraita* (Torah prohibition e.g. served them treif meat) vs
  *d'rabbanan* (Rabbinic prohibition e.g. served them chicken in a milky sauce).
- Will the answer differ if there is a reputational damage at stake? E.g. they or others will refuse to eat by you in future.

Comment: see Choshen Mishpat 234:3 especially the nesivos

Comment: What would be the point of informing people of such a fact?

Comment: @Israel so they can repent

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/132531/6592

Comment: @DoubleAA What does the victim need to repent for? They were bamboozled into committing the sin, that they were totally unaware of. אונס רחמנא פטריה. for example, unknowingly they were served treif meat, when they had all the right to assume that their host was a שומר מצוות, and עד אחד נאמן באיסורים.

Comment: @IsraelReader the question is not about bamboozling

Comment: @RabbiKaii bam·boo·zle VERB informal fool or cheat (someone). - Even less. if the person accidentally served them something that shouldn't be eating. Why is there any need for the victim to repent? What "sin" would they be "repenting" for? Why would you consider them to have a Torah liability for what happened to them, unknowingly and unwittingly? Are they at fault for anything?

Comment: @IsraelReader you are only dealing with ones. See https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Choshen_Mishpat.234.3?lang=he&with=Netivot%20HaMishpat,%20Beurim&lang2=he as DoubleAA mentioned

Comment: @IsraelReader it's an old machloket (horyot, etc.) if they would be considered shogeig or oneis.

Comment: Pretty sure this has been addressed on J.SE in the past at some point. But as above -- see the Nesivos. This actually came up at a yeshiva that served "the most amazing I-can't-believe-it's-not-milchigs" frozen dessert after a fleishigs meal; the mashgiach told the kitchen manager about the Nesivos -- a shogeg on a derabanan does not need kapara.

Comment: Certainly an interesting question. Interestingly, Rav Breitowitz (Ohr Sameach) adresses a like minded question with regards to a mashgiach who knowingly certified non kosher food. You can view the Question and Answer on video [HERE](https://youtu.be/FRbPAa2Wt4w?si=iWLS6hphgs7NhDnx&t=1401)

Answer (score 1):

The rabbis did not want to look too closely at the lineage of people.   In Kiddushin 71b, Ulla said : [You are worried about finding a wife with good lineage for your son?] Do *we* know where we come from? Can we be sure that *our* lineage is unflawed? Perhaps we are from those about whom it is written: “They have ravished the women in Zion, the maidens in the cities of Judah” (Lamentations 5:11).   Another rabbi (ref?) said he could spot mamzerim on sight, but would say nothing, especially because some gedolei Yisrael were among them.  Point: Don't stir the pot if no good can come out of doing so.  Let sleeping dogs lie.  If the person you wronged does not recognize by himself you did so and suffered no harm, you are under no obligation to confess to him.